# Omitting чтoбы in certain contexts

Tags: грамматика, синтаксис

So I was talking with a friend and he said:

> У мeня нeт дeнeг плaтить зa нaшe cвидaниe

I asked him if I could use чтoбы, and he said that also sounded fine. So is there a rule for the situations where you can omit чтoбы? If someone  can link some Russian sources that would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a very good question. Indeed, in some contexts **что́бы** can be dropped. These include:

VERB + что́бы + INFINITIVE:

- Я пришёл[, что́бы] поговори́ть с тобо́й.
- Я звоню́[, что́бы] сказа́ть, что не смогу́ прие́хать.
- Я ходи́л в магази́н[, что́бы] купи́ть молока́.

NOUN + что́бы + INFINITIVE:

- У меня́ есть по́вод[, что́бы] напи́ться.
- У меня́ есть де́ньги[, что́бы] заплати́ть за учёбу.
- У меня́ есть все возмо́жности[, что́бы] заверши́ть на́чатое.
- У меня́ есть вре́мя[, что́бы] приспосо́биться к но́вым пра́вилам.

It depends on the specific NOUN whether you can drop что́бы. Sometimes you can't drop it:

- У меня́ есть **ру́чка**, что́бы писа́ть.

Sometimes you don't need что́бы at all:

- У меня́ есть **жела́ние** пое́хать в о́тпуск.
- У меня́ была́ **попы́тка** бро́сить кури́ть.

This is by no means a definitive answer. Whether or not you can use or drop что́бы depends on the concrete noun or verb phrase being used.

Comment: Pretty interesting, thanks. Do you know any sources that talk about this a little more into detail?

Comment: A few cases where _чтoбы_ can't be omitted.  It strongly depends on the specific VERB whether you can drop _чтoбы_. For example, you cannot drop _чтобы_ in _Я ем, чтобы жить, или живу, чтобы есть?_ You can't drop it if there's _не_ between the verb and the infinitive: _Он бежал, чтобы не опоздать_. And you can never drop _чтобы_ in _желательно / нужно / нельзя, чтобы N сделал Х_. Also, if _чтобы_ is a part of compound subordinate conjunctions _для того(, ) чтобы_ and the like, it can't be dropped, either.

Comment: @YellowSky I completely agree, I just tried to keep my answer short by mostly sticking to cases where чтобы CAN be dropped. Thank you for your valuable additions.

Comment: @ЛугеУшчимі No, unfortunately, I couldn't find any information on the topic so I had to do my own research by skimming through a few pages of ruscorpora search results to see where чтобы can be dropped.

Comment: Note that removing чтобы changes the sentence structure and can affect meaning: 1. Мне не нужны твои поводы напиться. 'I don't need your reasons-to-get-drunk' (because I'm staying sober) 2. Мне не нужны твои поводы, чтобы напиться. 'I don't need your reasons to get drunk' (because I'm getting drunk anyway).

Comment: @ЛугеУшчимі I kept a few examples of RusCorpora results which I annotated with [чтобы] to indicate cases where it can be dropped: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bDue2gVG8iKN0GyzXqo3EQYAhhRbmxb0FLRFiYDdkrI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @SergeySlepov thanks for the work mate, really appreciate it